JSch session.connect error : Algorithm negotiation fail
Trying to connect to SFTP server via Jsch , I am using com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.1.72
Get following error at: session.connect().
I checked another SO(JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail) but the underlying error is different.
Jsch logs are as follows:
Connecting to SERVER_NAME port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-Serv-U_15.4.2.157
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.72
INFO: CheckCiphers: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
INFO: CheckKexes: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve448-sha512
INFO: CheckSignatures: ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed448
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal before known_host reordering is: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal after known_host reordering is: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO: kex: server: ssh-dss
INFO: kex: server: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server:
INFO: kex: server:
INFO: kex: client: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
INFO: kex: client: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
INFO: kex: client: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: kex: client: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client:
INFO: kex: client:
INFO: Disconnecting from SERVER_NAME port 22


0.1.72 is 3 years old. Why don't you try the latest one?

That server offers ONLY ssh-dss for server auth (i.e. only a DSA server key) and the mwiede Jsch's default config disallows ssh-dss, perhaps following OpenSSH which default-disabled it in '15 and will soon delete it entirely. If your app has config logic it can override this, otherwise set a sysprop as per https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/?tab=readme-ov-file @MartinPrikryl: recent versions retain this, and since 0.2.0 in Jan '22 also default-disable ssh-rsa -- like OpenSSH since 8.8 in Sep '21. Coincidence?

I was able to fix this with following setup:
session.setConfig("kex", session.getConfig("kex") + ",diffie-hellman-group1-sha1")
session.setConfig("server_host_key", session.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-dss")


That makes the connection rather insecure.

I don't have control over server

Understood, but your answer should be clear about the consequences.
